# Rails 3 Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 models, activity and city

```
class activity
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
  belongs_to city
end

class city
  has_many :activties
end

city_controller
  @activity_deals = @city.activities.find_all_by_deals(true)
end
```

View city

```
 - @activity_deals.attachments.each do |a|
    = image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px" )
       = a.description
```

I get the error `undefined method`attachments' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@activity_deals` will be an `Array` of `Activity` objects, not a single `Activity` object.

I'm not a HAML user, so I might be getting the syntax wrong, but you can probably use something a bit like this:

```
 - @activity_deals.each do |activity|
    - activity.attachments.each do |a|
      = image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px" )
         = a.description
```

Make sure you look at the whole error message, it will help you debug this kind of problem. The whole message will be something like `undefined method 'attachments' for […]:Array`, which tells you that you're calling `attachments` on an `Array`, not an `Activity`.

Comment: it works! Thanks..

the HAML code generate a jquery content slider for all the activity deals in the city x. I also have a event model with the same relationships as activity. Can i combined events and activity in one query and store the output in @activity_event_deals ?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a class `Attachement`? you are trying to call a the attachment class: `- @activity_deals.attachments.each`... but you are getting `undefined method`...
So, you must add this class to you application:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
end
```

However, I think you are trying to use [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

If so:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
end

class activity
  has_many :attachments, :as => :attachable 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
  belongs_to city
end

class city
  has_many :activties
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view city, `@activity_deals` is an array. So there is no "attachments" defined method on it.

You have to access to attachments on each element of you array.

Like that :

```
- @activity_deals.attachments.each do |a|
= image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px" )
   = a.description

- @activity_deals.each do |deal|
  - deal.attachments.each do |a|
    = image_tag(a.file.url, :height =>"325px", :width =>"650px" )
      = a.description
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are caling attachments methods on an array of activities.. Thats why its giving you error undefined ethod attacments .  please give u error log